# Recurrence formula for boxed plane partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'm looking for a nice recurrence formula for the number $[r,s,t]$ of $(r,s,t)$-boxed plane partitions in analogy to the recurrence formula
$$ [r,s]=[r-1,s]+[r,s-1]$$
for the binomial coefficient $[r,s]=\binom{r+s}{r}$ aka the number of $(r,s)$-boxed partitions.

What I found is this:
$$[r,s,t][r,s-1,t-1]=[r,s-1,t][r,s,t-1]+[r+1,s-1,t-1][r-1,s,t].$$

Setting $t=1$, this gives the recurrence formula for binomial coefficients. However, as in this case I would like to have a formula that is symmetric in $r$, $s$ and $t$. Is there something known?

Comment: Explicit formula is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition#Plane_partitions_in_a_box

Comment: "Dodgson condensation" for determinants (or "Kuo condensation" for counting perfect matchings) gives you a recurrence satisfied by the number of boxed plane partitions: see e.g. pg. 60 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2562.pdf.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thx, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 1):

At very least, we can symmetrize your recurrence by summing it over the $3!=6$ permutations of $r,s,t$ with element relabeling to keep $[r,s,t]$ in the l.h.s.
This gives the following symmetric recurrence:
\begin{split}
& [r,s,t]\big([r,s-1,t-1]+[r-1,s,t-1]+[r-1,s-1,t]\big) \\
&= [r,s-1,t][r,s,t-1] + [r-1,s,t][r,s-1,t] + [r-1,s,t][r,s,t-1] \\
&\quad + [r+1,s-1,t-1][r-1,s,t] + [r-1,s+1,t-1][r,s-1,t] + [r-1,s-1,t+1][r,s,t-1].
\end{split}

Comment: Thx for your answer. Sorry, but I had a typo in my formula, which you reproduced.

Comment: @BipolarMinds: I've updated my answer accordningly.